# How can I tell if a seed coating contains pesticides or fungicides?

Tags: seeds, poisons, pesticide

I purchased some [Dichondra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dichondra) seeds online to plant in my large reptile's enclosure. There was no mention of the seeds being treated - but when I received them I noticed that the seeds were coated and listed as pre-inoculated.

I'm not generally one to be overly paranoid about pesticides & fungicides but reptiles tend to be pretty sensitive to such things so I absolutely can't risk planting treated seeds. Is there any way to tell if the seeds in question are fungicide/pesticide treated? The seller didn't know, and while I'd assume there are some labeling laws for treated seeds I can't find any information on what those are. Does anyone have any idea as to what the seed coating is and whether or not it poses a risk to my lizard?

Comment: In the context of seeds, [inoculation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microbial_inoculant) usually means coating them with beneficial bacteria or fungi to help the seeds grow. I can't help with the identification part of the question, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Canada, seeds that have a poisonous coating (pesticide, fungicide etc) are always bright pink. A quick search appears to imply that this is also true in the US.

[image]

This picture from [Ray Weil](http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/xM9KTJg2T4OvmJHH5vqVVg) demonstrates a typical difference between treated and untreated. The source of the seed is not mentioned but the picture was taken in Mexico.

Comment: Thanks - I really appreciate it. I decided to move away from the dichondra because of some potential skin irritation issues - but this puts my mind at ease quite a bit. I thought there were some rules regarding this but wasn't sure. Thanks!